# How can I get a count of times a value occurs by date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has a lot of values, but the only ones I care about are year, day, month, and contributing_factor.

How can I write a query such that it gives the the number of times each contributing_factor value appears per day?

Example:

year, month, day, contributing_factor, timesOccurred,

2017, 10, 21, Driver distracted, 48

I have tried using

```
SELECT `year`,`day`,`month`, CONTRIBUTING_FACTOR_VEHICLE_1, COUNT(CONTRIBUTING_FACTOR_VEHICLE_1) as occurrences
FROM table
GROUP BY CONTRIBUTING_FACTOR_VEHICLE_1
```

but I cannot figure out a way to write it such that I am not getting an error 1055.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a date column as parameter to functions, and you need to include the same in the group by clause e.g.

```
SELECT
       year(datecol)
     , month(datecol)
     , day(datecol)
     , CONTRIBUTING_FACTOR_VEHICLE_1
     , COUNT(*) as occurrences 
FROM table 
GROUP BY 
       year(datecol)
     , month(datecol)
     , day(datecol)
     , CONTRIBUTING_FACTOR_VEHICLE_1
 ;
```

Please note that it might appear inefficient to repeat those 3 function calls in the group by clause - but it isn't. The way an SQL query works is that the GROUP BY clause is performed BEFORE the select clause, so you do not make the query less efficient.

Also, SQL standards require that all* "non-aggregating" columns of the select clause also be used in the group by clause.

all* except when there is "functional dependency" and some other edge cases, from a purely practical standpoint just repeat all non-aggregating columns (i.e. all columns not using COUNT() MIN() MAX() AVG() etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I would actually suggest using the `date()` function:

```
SELECT date(daatecol), CONTRIBUTING_FACTOR_VEHICLE_1, 
       COUNT(*) as occurrences
FROM table
GROUP BY date(daatecol), CONTRIBUTING_FACTOR_VEHICLE_1;
```

I think a date column is simpler to work with than three separate values for year, month, and day.

Answer (score 0):

It **sounds** like you're just looking for
`SELECT COUNT(contributing_factor) FROM [TABLE] WHERE day = [DAY]`

Though assuming you're unable to use a simple `WHERE` clause, you can try relying on the fact that `COUNT` only counts non-null values:

`SELECT COUNT(CASE contributing_factor WHEN day = [DAY] THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
FROM [TABLE].`

Comment: The issue is that I want it for ALL days along 5 years individually. WHat you suggested would be fine if I wanted just my example